# What race invaded Jack's home world?

Tags: torchwood

In *Adam*, the episode with the alien Adam who can manipulate memories, Jack is explaining the memory of when he lost his younger brother. He described the invaders of his home world as possibly being the worst race in the universe, yet he never names them.

At first, I thought that maybe it was the Daleks, but then I remembered that Jack said that the invaders had passed by his home many times, which seems uncharacteristic for Daleks.

So what was the race that invaded Jack's home?

Comment: I don't think it's known. Tardis wikia has no info on it.

Comment: I had the impression that this was deliberately left open by the writers, so that future writers would be able to expand on it.

Answer (score 2):

**In short, we don't know.** 
It's not revealed in the show, or any of the supplementary literature (such as the prose novels).

Given the cancellation of Torchwood, unless there's a surprise "word of god" revelation from Barrowman, Moffat or another Doctor Who insider, it's unlikely we'll ever find out.

Comment: For the record, there's a tiny snippet in the novel "[The Twilight Streets](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Boeshane_Peninsula)" that confirms that Boeshane is an Earth colony but that's the only extra info that exists in any of the supplementary materials.